# Why is appearing the html instead of the icon font?

Tags: jquery

I have this link:

```
<a class="name" id="showProducs" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal2" href="">
  Show products
  <i class="fa fa-caret-down" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</a>
```

When is clicked instead of "Show products" should appear the selected item text in the modal. So I have his jQUery

```
$("a[name='showProducts']").on('click', function(){
  $('#showProducts').text($(this).text()+'<i class="fa fa-caret-down" aria-hidden="true"></i>');
});
```

The issue is that the instaed of appear the icon font is appearing the html `<i class="fa fa-caret-down" aria-hidden="true"></i>` instead of the icon font.

Do you know why?

Comment: Change `$('#showProducts').text(` to `$('#showProducts').html(`

Comment: It would be helpful if your markup reflected what your logic actually is using.  As it stands, your provided script would not do anything because the `a` tag does not have a name, and the internal id lookup does not match the id on the link either.  So if your script is indeed actually changing the value of the link, then you have not provided either the exact script or markup that you are actually having an issue with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$("a[name='showProducts']").on('click', function(){ $('#showProducts').html($(this).text()+'<i class="fa fa-caret-down" aria-hidden="true"></i>'); });
```

Just Replace .text() to .html()